# jQuery Autocomplete with Caching from a url based on other options

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-app-engine, caching, jquery-autocomplete

I have been struggling with this project for a few days and I am hoping that I could get some help.  I have the following protected url:

```
/item/code?comp=comp1
```

This returns the data as json of all codes a company has in the following format:

```
[{'code':'test1','hdescrip':'Test code 1','type':'test type', etc.},and so on]
```

I have two components then on the web page:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="79">Search Type</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="type_chk[]" id="type_chk" value="group" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="type_chk">Group</label>
           </td>
        <td ><input type="checkbox" name="type_chk[]" id="type_chk" value="pick" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="type_chk">Pick List</label></td>
        <td ><input type="checkbox" name="type_chk[]" id="type_chk"  value="item" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="type_chk">Item</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="type_chk[]" id="type_chk" value="service" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="type_chk">Service</label></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" width="6" id="code" name="code" /><label for="code">Code</label></td>
        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" width="75" id="hdescrip" name="hdescrip" /><label for="hdescrip">Description</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It is expensive to call and search for partial matches on my database considering the code portion has 1000s of possible items which have similar code and description.  What I would like to do is load the database based on the selection of type of codes and set that as the source for the autocomplete for each of the respective inputs in the table.

So if they declick group for example, the new url for the source would be `/item/code?comp=comp1&type_chk="pick,item,service` which should be cached browser side - I have seen people use the `var cache = {}` method but I don't think that is correct.  This cache should be used as the source data for the code autocomplete and then match the hdescrip component of the passed data to the hdescrip input text.

I know how to set it up as an ajax call, but I don't want to constantly ping the database.

Also, this is on google app engine so I cannot create static files.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Jon

Comment: It seems like you want to load a new JSON object containing updated data from the database based on selection, then search that. Correct?

Comment: yes exactly - I also want to update the other field on selection - which I know how to do, but it is this browser side caching which I would want since it will save significant read resources on the server.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you will need a piece of server side code that will query the database both onLoad of the page and onSelection.

Your algorithm:

> 1. Connect to database and execute query.
> 2. Return dataset and create JSON string from array set returned
> 3. Save JSON to a file
> 4. Query said JSON file or Object returned for parsing
> 5. repeat #1 - #4 onSelect

Your code for #1 and #3 would look like this:

```
var myJSON = {};

function getData(something){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getDataFromDB.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: 'parameter=something',
      success: function(data) {
        //called when successful
        myJSON = data;
      },
      error: function(e) {
        //called when there is an error
        //console.log(e.message);
      }
    });
}
```

Your code in #2 might look like this - if using PHP (you can use other languages of course)

```
$return_arr = array();
$something = $_GET['parameter'];

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table where column = $something"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['col1'] = $row['col1'];
    $row_array['col2'] = $row['col2'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

$newJSON = json_encode($return_arr);

$destination = "myData.json";
file_put_contents($destination, minifyJson($newJSON));
```

Then your code in #4 might begin with something like this:

```
var myJSONData = {};

function getJSONData(){
    $.getJSON( "myData.json", function( data ) {
      console.log(data); //dump out the json object returned
      myJSONData = data;
    });
}

$('#someID').onClick(function(){
  var selection = $('#someID').val();
  getData(selection);
});
```

From there you can fire off the above function onClick and pass parameters to your PHP file via a query string and use `$_GET['parameter']` to manipulate what comes back from the database. You an expect to tweak the above code a bit, but this should give you a general idea. Good luck.